# Bazaar (bzr) integration with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, bazaar

What's the best way to use Bazaar (bzr) as the version control system in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Haha, I wonder how long VS will be locked up then!

Comment: I've not tested TortoiseBZR, but as far as I'm concerned, TortoiseBZR is not for me anyway. I'm a pure x64 guy and it's not integrated with VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best I found is [TortoiseBZR](http://bazaar-vcs.org/TortoiseBzr) and the command-line - nothing integrated with VS.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't even bother with TortoiseBZR; bzr is very easy to use from the command line.

BTW: The last time I tried it, TortoiseBZR used to lock up windows explorer while it went off to a remote repository to determine the status of files, not sure if it still does this ... ? [See also this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151587/how-do-i-disable-tortoise-bzr).

Answer (score 4):

There is no native integration to Visual Studio, but there is good GUI application, called Bazaar Explorer. It's the part of official standalone installer, and also can be installed separately as bzr plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Old, I know, but since this shows up on the top for Google search, the best way to integrate is a combination of Visual Studio's External Tools, and tbzrcommand.exe and bzr.exe. You can set up things like Status to go to the output window, and things like Diff to go to the tbzrcommand GUI window.

(I'm assuming you've installed TortoiseBzr here.) Using these as examples, in VS open Tools->External Tools, then Add. For the program, browse to the Bazaar directory and select bzr.exe. Name the command Status. For arguments, type "status" (sans quotes). Select that the output should be directed to the vs output window, that the command should be terminated when complete. Open a simple file under code control and add a space somewhere and save, then under external tools, choose status to verify that it shows up as a pending commit action. (You can add these to their own menu later, once they work.)

Next, add another external command and name this Diff. For the program, browse to the Bazaar directory, and choose tbzrcommand.exe. For arguments, type "--command=diff --file=$(TargetPath)" (sans quotes). Leave the options all unchecked. Then, for the file above that you added a space, select it in the solution explorer window and choose Tools->Diff. A TortoiseBzr window should appear (along with an annoying DOS window), and show differences between the working version and the latest commit version of the file.

For something like a commit, which requires a comment, you'll have to put in arguments like "commit -m " (sans quotes) and check the box to prompt for arguments (to allow the entry of a message for the commit).

Comment: Even better: use `qdiff` and `qcommit` to bring up the graphical diff and commit windows.

Answer (score 2):

[There's a project in Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/bzr-visualstudio), but it looks like it's abandoned, and when I downloaded it, I couldn't get it to build.

This is something I'm interested in myself.  Tracking adds, drops and renames automatically in an IDE is the way to go.  Seeing status is nice too.

Comment: http://bazaar-vcs.org/VisualStudioIntegration -- there explained how to get it working.

Comment: Yeah.  Klaus updated it recently with build instructions for VS2008.  It builds for me now, but I haven't got it working.  I'm still poking at it in my copious free time.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the SCC integration, just the ability to use the tool, try the setup in this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/Bazaar4VS.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've ported VisualHG to work with Bazaar:
https://launchpad.net/visualbzr

It's currently an alpha version, and has only been built and tested for Visual Studio 2010, but common operations should work OK.

Edit:
This plugin hasn't moved on much, but it does now support Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Unified SCC has support for bzr. It is commercial but claims to be free for OSS projects.

[UnifiedSCC](http://aigenta.com/products/UnifiedScc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I too was trying to use this, and found that visual studio has an option of "External Tools", which can be found under the tools tool bar. Upon trial, I found that one could create a link to the bzr.exe (or any other exe tools you may want to use). Then, it asks for arguements. It is here where you can begin to use magic.

For me, to commit changes directly, I have created an arguement of commit -m "", which commits without message to the bzr branch if one exists in the working directory (to achieve this, you also have to change the starting directory to solution directory).

I also created a push command to my launchpad using similar idealogy